# Android L - Icon background color

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to color the icon's background of my notifications on `Android L`. I think I saw an API during `GoogleIO` and the attached image actually shows a green background, but I can't find anything on the documentation.
Can you point me to something?

BONUS QUESTION: How about the background color for Wear Notification? Does it use the same API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This color can be changed like this:

```
.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_primary))
```